# asp.net mvc - value provider and collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to access in my ActionFilter a property. This propert is a collection.

Usually I access the values using the valueprovider like this

```
filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("Prop");
```

but this isn't working in case of a collection.

Is there way to get my collection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `filterContext.ActionParameters`. Example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Action filter:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var value = filterContext.ActionParameters["model"];
        // TODO: do something with the value
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Request: `/?collection[0]=foo&collection[1]=bar`

Comment: Very nice, but ActionParameters isn't available in the OnActionExecuted overload.

Comment: @user256034, `OnActionExecuted` is invoked after the action has finished executing so I wonder why you might need to retrieve this information so lately.

Comment: Its a request for data of a grid control. There is property with column names to fetch.  This property goes to a repository where an IEnumerable is returned. This IEnumerable is returned to the view. But that's not everything. Those data must be in a special grid control specific XML format. I'd like the way how the actionfilter can decuple the "IEnumerable to XML" logic. But I need the column names from the action parameter.

Comment: Needless to say its an AJAX request.. and I found a solution. I introduced a fieldin my action filter class. This field is filled in OnActionExecuting and then in OnActionExecuted I'll just read the value from the field.What do you think about it ?

Comment: I think that if your data grid expects the results in a special format you could also use a custom `ActionResult` instead of action filters. Now your controller action could simply `return YourCustomResult(someModelObject);` and this custom action result will take care of properly formatting the data.

Comment: You're right! A custom actionresult is a much more cleaner solution. BTW Is there any way to access action paramter from the ControllerContext ? :-)

Comment: @user256034, not that I am aware of. But if you use a custom action result you could simply pass whatever information is necessary for generating the custom format in its constructor.